# Reference variable's type in a type definition of another

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in TypeScript to reference the type of one variable (in this example `someVar`) in the type declaration of another (`anotherVar`)?

Let's say I wouldn't like to create a new type declaration for `{ complex: 'type' }`, just insert it in place as type for `someVar`. Then, later in code, I'd like to conditionally set `anotherVal` to the value of `someVar` and otherwise leave it undefined. I don't want to use `any` as its type, but the same as `someVar` has.

```js
const someVar?: { complex: 'type' } // = ...

// ...

// What I would like in pseudocode:
let anotherVar/*: (typeof someVar) */ = undefined

if (condition) {
  anotherVar = someVar
}
```

---

Edited: It seems TypeScript has a `typeof` operator (and above pseudocode is also valid TypeScript code), but it doesn't work well in all cases, specifically with `this`.

A slightly different example:

```js
class Test {
  private someVar?: { complex: 'type' } // = ...

  private someMethod() {
    let anotherVar: typeof this.someVar = undefined // Error: Cannot find name 'this'.

    if (condition) {
      anotherVar = someVar
    }
  }
}
```

What to do in the above case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `typeof` can be used exactly like you've shown in your pseudocode. [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAvgbgFDYMZwB2AzsFMXALYQBqAhgE4BcsCyaW2ANhGXYXGAALCA3rMoAClCQ4AM3JVajAJTsMmKAHotUGRBbw4QA)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Wow, thanks :D I couldn't find the solution by googling and didn't come up with the idea of randomly trying if it just works :D

Comment: I've added a more complex example with a class. This operator doesn't seem to work with class members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `keyof` operator doesn't work for `this`. There was a [proposal about this on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/6606) but it has been closed and likely won't be implemented. The best alternative I think would be to lookup the type of the member from the class like this:

```js
class Test {
  private someVar?: { complex: 'type' } // = ...

  private someMethod() {
    let anotherVar: Test["someVar"] = undefined

    if (condition) {
      anotherVar = someVar
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0AOAnAlgG5hLzQQD2AtvAGpi4D8AXGtMNdiPAB6sDkSAJ7Z4-aAF9oAemnQAvNAB0K9JhwFipctXgBZeEgAWFACYAKAJRp1WbijAA7Csfi56uVgmQBtAESUNB5+ALoK0ACujqbwAGb4jvCmalhY+LHQ5hzR+Ej4FI7WGKmpTi5Gbh7hgXQMtpLqEugSQA)

---

Of course, as @Skovy said, you could also extract the type of `someVar` into a type and reference it in both places. IMO this is the preferable solution, unless you have some reason not to.

```js
type ComplexType = { complex: 'type' } | undefined;

class Test {
  private someVar?: ComplexType;

  private someMethod() {
    let anotherVar: ComplexType = undefined

    if (condition) {
      anotherVar = this.someVar
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Test["someVar"]` doesn't look that bad, but what's weird,is that it can't be used interchangeably with `Test.someVar`. Too bad `this` isn't supported.

Comment: In case you want to read up some more on it, here are the [official docs for lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types)

Answer (score 2):

What you have already works:

```
type Friend = {
    name: string;
}

const fred: Friend = {
    name: 'Fred',
};

let george: typeof fred;
// Now george is also of type Friend
```

Comment: Right, I couldn't find the answer by quickly googling and made up this operator which seems to work as intended. I hope my question helps other people searching with similar keywords to me.

Comment: I've added a more complex example with a class. This operator doesn't seem to work with class members.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your example? In the example you provided, it does work, i.e. `typeof Test.prototype.someVar` is valid. So what is the situation that does not work?

Comment: Right, so I need to reference the variable by `ClassName.prototype.fieldName`. It's not that obvious unless you already know it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new `type` or `interface` and reuse it in both cases.

```js
type A = undefined | { complex: 'type' }

const someVar: A = { complex: 'type'};

let anotherVar: A = undefined

let condition = true;
if (condition) {
  anotherVar = someVar
}
```

You can also use the `typeof` operator like you suggested:

```js
let someVar: { complex: 'type' } | undefined;

let anotherVar: typeof someVar = undefined

let condition = true;
if (condition) {
  anotherVar = someVar
}
```

As for the more complex class example I would try to use a `type` or `interface` for that as well:

```js
type A = { complex: 'type' } | undefined;

class Test {
  private someVar?: A;

  private someMethod() {
    let anotherVar: A = undefined

    let condition = true;
    if (condition) {
      anotherVar = this.someVar
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't seen this approach but it also seemed to work:

```js
class Test {
  private someVar?: { complex: 'type' }

  private someMethod() {
    let anotherVar: typeof Test.prototype.someVar = undefined

    let condition = true;
    if (condition) {
      anotherVar = this.someVar
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added a more complex example with a class. This operator doesn't seem to work with class members.